# How can incorrect information on a Catholic baptismal record be corrected?

Tags: catholicism, baptism

My mother was baptised Catholic in 1923 but the baptismal record has a few mistakes on it not least the mother's name.

Is it possible to have a baptismal record corrected and what forms of proof do I need to do so?

Comment: Catholic baptism, she is not registered in Northern Ireland where she was born but I found her baptism as stated. I have other siblings with birth certificates and Barnados records when her mother died.

Comment: This is anything but asking for pastoral advice. The question deals with Catholic formalities within a diocese. This is quite answerable according to the Catholic Church.

Comment: @KenGraham I agree with you, but to the defense of the close voters, I did edit it a bit whilst there were 4 close votes.

Comment: @KenGraham I respectfully disagree with you. The correct way to pursue this is to go in person to the local diocese.  The internet cannot help resolve this (which is sort of what's in your answer).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I fully  agree with you. Did not suspect my answer would be viewed as such.

Comment: I recently found out that my Baptismal certificate contains my fathers surname since I am preparing for my wedding. But for my whole life, and also indicated in my PSA birth cert, I am using my mother's maiden name. For Birth cert per se, it was late registered. (My father abandoned us when I was a kid and they were not legally married).
Do you have sample affidavit for the correction of my baptismal cert, that contains that the real name should be indicated is my mothers maiden name. Considering that the prevailing document is the Birth Certificate. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 4):

**How can incorrect information on a Catholic baptismal record be corrected?**

Start by going to the parish priest of the church in which the baptism actually occurred and explain it to the pastor in charge. This should be done in person and not over any sort of social media. Please phone in advance to make an appointment and to make sure the pastor not on holidays or way on business or studies. If you are know to the priest(s) of this parish church, there should not be too much difficulty in getting the records set straight. Make sure that you have all the pertinent information needed when you see him, such as official government issued IDs, the original baptismal certificate (if possible) and the appropriate birth certificates and or marriage certificates (if required because of a name change).

If this fails, then approach your local [chancery office](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diocesan_chancery) on how to proceed. If the baptism occurred at the cathedral (as in my case) you will need to start directly at the chancery office of the diocese. In this case the [Rector of the Cathedral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rector_(ecclesiastical)) would be able to assist you in making any corrections necessary on the baptismal records.

Comment: It may be relevant to consider what sort of "mistake" may be corrected. If a child was christened "Mary" and the record says "Anne" then witnesses might confirm that the priest had made a mistake. But if the child was christened "Anne" but subsequently known as Mary then that is no mistake and I don't think it can be "corrected". In UK law a name given in baptism is the person's legal name even if the child was civilly registered under a different name. In OPs case the baptism could have been of another child altogether and would that be altered?